# How to offset 2 cells of a range in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro that checks if a value is true, and if so takes the first cell of the row and stores it.  For example:

```
|191|c:users\public\test.dbf  |True |  
|192|c:users\public\test2.dbf |False|  
|193|c:users\public\test2.dbf |False|
```

I want to loop through this array and when a value is True I need to store 191 and c:users\public\test.dbf (for this example; the actual values to store will be dependent on the row).

Here is my code:

```
For Each strPath In Worksheets("OPTIONS").Range("F2:H6")
    newChemin = strPath
    If strPath <> True And strPath <> False Then Chemin = strPath

    If strPath.Value = "True" Then
        For Each Cell In Worksheets("OPTIONS").Range("F2:F6")
            If Cell = Chemin Then
                strChemin = Chemin
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Cell

        Set wsSheet1 = wbBook.Worksheets("DB" & strChemin)        
        If strPath.Value = "TRUE" Then
            If FichierExiste(Chemin) Then
                Line = Line + 1
            Else
                Chemin = Worksheets("OPTIONS").Cells(7, 7).Value & "\" & strChemin & "\ancretbd.mdb"
                If FichierExiste(Chemin) Then
                    '* Appel de la Method mod_Importation
                    Call Importation_Totale
                Else
                    MsgBox "Desolé, le fichié demandé n'existe pas !"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next strPath
```

Comment: How many times will you need to do this?

Comment: please don't code a range object `strPath` with str, as it confuses in stead of clarifies. Change it into (for example) `rPath` for more general clarity.

Comment: So, for reference - "Chemin" (French) means "Path" (English) and "FichierExiste" means "FileExists".  Can you also tell us how you're storing the values you want to save?  Why do you have multiple checks for `strPath.Value = "True"`?  What is the `Line` variable for?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the French (??) variables it is quite hard to understand what this code is doing.
If you can describe what a chemin is, maybe it is easier to understand what part of your row you are referring to.

However, as your strPath is actually a Range, you can simply refer to the offset of it!

```
For Each strPath In Worksheets("OPTIONS").Range("F2:H6")
    If strPath.Value = "True" Then
        Set wsSheet1 = wbBook.Worksheets("DB" & strPath.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If FichierExiste(strPath.Offset(0, -2).Value) Then
        Line = Line + 1
        Else
            Chemin = Worksheets("OPTIONS").Cells(7, 7).Value & "\" & strChemin & "\ancretbd.mdb"
            If FichierExiste(Chemin) Then
                 '* Appel de la Method mod_Importation
                 Call Importation_Totale
            Else
                MsgBox "Desolé, le fichié demandé n'existe pas !"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next strPath
```

This might not be 100% correct (because the function of the code is unclear to me), and probably the offsets are wrong (the -1 and -2 in the above example). But I hope this gives you an idea on fixing your problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that column H is the column containing TRUE or False. In this case, if you only want to check this column and update column F and G accordingly then this simplified code can do the job for you:

```
For Each strPath In Worksheets("OPTIONS").Range("H2:H6")
     If strPath.Value = "True" Then
         Range("F" & strPath.Row).Value = "191"
         Range("G" & strPath.Row).Value = "c:users\public\test.dbf"

     End If
Next
```